# How to generate document with 6 grid images, chapter header and table of contents

Tags: graphics, table-of-contents, hyperref, header-footer, chapters

I am trying to generate a booklet with a grid of 6 or less images in a grid, and a text caption below it.  I would like each page to display the chapter in the header, and have the table of contents link to the first page of the chapter.  This is the basic idea of what I'm after (it doesn't need to match the exact color scheme or anything):

[image]

This is my attempt at doing this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=1in]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lfoot{\today}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\cfoot{}
\rhead{}
\lhead{\leftmark}

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage\phantomsection
\tableofcontents

\clearpage\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 1}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\subfigure[t=0]{\frame{\includegraphics[width=150px]{569J-12}}}
\subfigure[t=10]{\frame{\includegraphics[width=150px]{80_Gas_Furnace}}}
\subfigure[t=20]{\frame{\includegraphics[width=150px]{90_Gas_Furnace}}}\\
\subfigure[t=0]{\frame{\includegraphics[width=150px]{569J-12}}}
\subfigure[t=10]{\frame{\includegraphics[width=150px]{80_Gas_Furnace}}}
\subfigure[t=20]{\frame{\includegraphics[width=150px]{90_Gas_Furnace}}}
\end{figure}

\includepdfset{pagecommand=\thispagestyle{fancy}}
\end{document}
```

The following is what I get with this code:

[image: actual result]

Comment: I get only one entry in the table of contents with this example. Or what is your problem?

Comment: I got my question answered from another one of my posts:

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174513/how-to-add-a-box-of-a-fixed-size-width-and-height-around-a-graphic-of-varying